# A word for the top plus point in one's application for a position?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When you apply for a position/job, one aspect of your application -- for example your proposal, or your research record, or your background -- is your greatest advantage to get you the position/job. I am looking for a word/phrase to mean such a top plus point.

Example:

I have applied for the position and I think my proposal would be my ------ .

The very common "greatest strength" that is asked about in interviews seems to be just about *personal features* or *character*. So that seems not to be the right word for the above sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Consider **selling point** or **unique selling point** ("unique" if you want to emphasize that you believe this attribute makes you stand out from the competition). This seems to be common in résumé writing advice:

[This site](https://resumes-for-teachers.com/blog/interview-tips/the-importance-of-selling-your-unique-selling-point/) has an example:

> When interviewing for any position [...] you need to know what differentiates yourself from all the other candidates. In other words, you need to understand the importance of utilizing your **unique selling point**.

Similarly, from employment site [Monster](https://www.monster.co.uk/career-advice/article/what-are-my-unique-selling-points):

> When a company is determining how to advertise their products to consumers, they focus on its unique selling points (USPs) - the things which make the product different from any other. It may be that it is smaller, lasts longer or tastes better than its competitors. The same principle applies to you when you are applying for a new job.
>
> You need to think about your **unique selling points**. What is the one reason that an employer should hire you above all other candidates? What can you bring that is unique or where can you add value to the position/company? What skills and experience do you have that will meet their needs?

This makes it clear that your [unique] selling point is not necessarily a personal strength, but can include specific experience. This would make it broader than "greatest strength" and fit your examples of research record or background.

Comment: Very good suggestion. Great Job!